# Can an earpiece transfer virus from one phone to another?

Tags: virus, ios, phone, iphone, audio

I gave a friend my earpiece and her phone had audio issues prior to that, I took it back and connected it to my phone and ever since I did, my audio stopped working. Now if I try to do anything that has audio my phone lags. I use an iPhone X, she uses a 7+

Comment: Please share the model number of the earpiece.

Comment: This is a quick jump from "audio issues" to virus, ignoring other possible reasons for the problem. But in general: many modern head phones have firmware which can be updated using the phone. And firmware might have bugs which can cause problems. But head phones might also get physical defects which are not expected by the firmware which then reacts in strange ways.

Comment: Was it bluetooth? Then the duplicate answers you. Was it wired? Then no.

Answer (score -1):

When you say "earpiece" I am assuming a phone accessory for transmitting audio signals, typically connected to a phone through a jack or so, depending on the brand of phone. If this is true, **NO** is the answer. Earpiece cannot transfer a virus from one phone to another. Viruses or malware are typically software-based threats that exploit vulnerabilities in the operating system or applications of a device. Earpieces are hardware accessories that are designed to transmit audio signals and do not have the capability to execute or transmit software code. It is possible that the earpiece jack has damaged something in your phone, I recommend you visit a service centre for proper diagnosis and repair.

Comment: The brand of the phone is iPhone which doesn't have a headphone jack... and the friend's phone also had problems. So, I'm not sure this answer applies at all.

Comment: @schroeder down voting my answer appears malicious to me. The OP didn't indicate if it was a bluetooth device or not. Besides, the question was modified because at the time I responded, the model of the phones weren't specified. This platform is for learning not for witch-hunting. Thanks

Comment: It's not malicious. The tooltip on the down arrow says "The answer is not useful". It's not a reflection on you as a person. The device doesn't have a headphone jack, and even if it did, focusing on damage to the jack would be strange if both phones had the same problem. Hence, the answer is not useful. The question hasn't been edited; it was up for 7 hours before you posted your answer. There is no witch hunt.